How to arrive at this conclusion regarding the asymptotic analysis of integer points inside a sphere with k ≥ 4 dimensions?
In the problem of sum of squares function, we defined that $$ r_k(n) = \#\{(x_1,x_2,\cdots, x_k)\in \mathbb{Z}^k|n=x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_k^2\}$$
it is the number of ways to represent any natural number n as the sum of k squared numbers.
Now consider performing asymptotic analysis on $\displaystyle\sum_{n\le x}r_k(n)$. According to the conclusion of Jacobi's sum of four squares: $r_4(n)=8\displaystyle\sum_{4\nmid d\mid n}d$ . We can get
$$r_4(n)=\dfrac{\pi^2x^2}2+\mathcal{O}(x\log x)$$
In Henryk Iwaniec and Emmanuel Kowalski's book Analytical Number Theory, formula 1.76 on page 22 states:
This result extends easily for any $k\ge 4$ (Write the $r_k$ as the additive convolution of $r_4$ and $r_{k-4}$ , apply the above result for $r_4$ and execute the summation over the remaining $k-4$ squares by integration)
$$\sum_{n\le x}r_k(n)=\dfrac{(\pi x)^{\frac k2}}{\Gamma\left(\frac k2+1\right)}+\mathcal{O}\left(x^{\frac k2-1}\log x\right)\tag{1}$$
I think the term 'additive convolution' mentioned by the author should refer to the following formula:$r_k(n)=\displaystyle\sum_{m=0}^n r_{k-4}(m)r_{4}(n-m)$.
How should the above process be carried out specifically?
I tried the above process and obtained the following thinking results:
$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n\le x}r_k(n)&=\sum_{n\le x}\sum_{m=0}^n r_{k-4}(m)r_4(n-m)\\
&=\sum_{m\le x}r_{k-4}(m)\sum_{m\le n\le x}r_4(n-m)\\
&=\sum_{m\le x}r_{k-4}(m)\sum_{n'\le {x-m}}r_4(n')\qquad(n'=n-m)\\
&=\dfrac{\pi^2}2\sum_{m\le x}(x-m)^2r_{k-4}(m)+\sum_{m\le x}r_{k-4}(m)\mathcal{O}\left[(x-m)\log(x-m)\right]
\end{align*}$$
So what should we do next to get $(1)$ ?Will the following progressive formula be used:
$$\sum_{n\le x}r_k(n)=\dfrac{(\pi x)^\frac k2}{\Gamma\left(\frac k2+1\right)}+\mathcal{O}\left(x^\frac{k-1}2\right)$$
In addition, the author also mentioned that the exponent $\frac k2-1$ in the remaining terms is already the optimal coefficient. How should we understand it?
(P.S. I am not a native English speaker, so some expressions may not be accurate enough.)

Your $n$'s and $k$'s are all confused in your opening paragraph. I suggest some proofreading.

Thank you for your reminder. I have corrected the areas that may have caused confusion

your final expression contains the sum of $r_{k-4}$ except it has a weight. but the weight is actually better than no weight (it's smoother) so you can write it as an integral for example, pull the integral out so you have a sum of just $r_{k-4}$.
